# Overriding +/-/*/% by integer and the -Weffc++ flag

Tags: c++, warnings

I have a class called Coord...it has instance data x, y. I want to override the * operator such that the * operator can be used to multiply the Coord by an integer or double! This is the solution I put up:

```
Coord& Coord::operator*(int n)
{
    this->x = this->x*n;
    this->y = this->y*n;
    return *this;
}
```

It works - I've tested some print outs from main...the only issue is...I get a warning from the -Weffc++ flag! It says my function should return by value! I know this flag corresponds to the book "Effective C++" book, but I don't have a copy onhand - what does the book suggest? What is meant to pass by value?

Comment: The problem it is telling you about is, that the `operator*` should return a newly created object, instead of modifying the existing object (that is what `*=` is for afterall). In that case you would return a reference to a local variable, which is obviously wrong. if you overload operators, please **make them behave like the operator normally does**

Comment: btw, Scott Meyers also suggests returning `const Coord` so you can't `(a * b) = c;`.

Comment: @chris: That advice is outdated unfortunately, as it disables moving.

Comment: @chris: That advice should be deprecated in the light of C++11 and move constructors/assignment though

Comment: Yeah, good point. I really wish he'd have written one since C++11 came into play. I just happened to remember since I was reading it a couple days ago.

Comment: A bit of coding advice: the `this->`s are unnecessary and distracting. Much clearer: `x *= n; y *= n;`. And, since it modifies `*this`, this function's name really should be `*=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Grizzly's comment...  This is not the in-place multiplication.  As such, you should declare it const to explicitly prevent that:

```
Coord Coord::operator*(int n) const {
    Coord c(*this);
    c.x *= n;
    c.y *= n;
    return c;
}
```

Or if you have a useful constructor:

```
Coord Coord::operator*(int n) const {
    return Coord(x*n, y*n);
}
```

The in-place multiplication is different (and non-const):

```
Coord& Coord::operator*=(int n) {
    x *= n;
    y *= n;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't implemented `operator*` but rather you implemented the self-mutating `operator*=`, assigning the result back to the original object.

Consider the effects of your operator's implementation for the following `int` example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 2;
int z = x * y;
```

Now, with integer multiplication implemented similarly to your code, you would end up with both `y` *and* `z` equal to 10.

In order to implement the normal `operator*` type operators you'll need to create a temporary object and return that by value.

You're probably looking for an implementation more like this (assuming you have a two parameter constructor to your class):

```
Coord Coord::operator*(int n) const
{
    return Coord(x * n, y * n);
}
```

But note that often, what seems like an obvious meaning of an operator isn't so clear, and overloading simply causes confusion. Consider a non-member named function instead (using a named member scaling function), along these lines:

```
Coord& Coord::ScaleBy(int n)
{
    this->x = this->x*n;
    this->y = this->y*n;
    return *this;
}

Coord ScaleCoord(Coord c, int n)
{
    return c.ScaleBy(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, this sort of thing is done in two parts, a member `operator*=` and a non-member `operator*` that uses `*=`:

```
Coord& Coord::operator*=(int n) {
    x *= n;
    y *= n;
    return *this;
}

Coord operator*(const Coord& c, int n) {
    Coord res(c);
    res *= n;
    return res;
}
```